# TypeError: data type not understood model?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, machine-translation

I am trying to predict my NMT model but I am getting an error I do not know.

what is happening exactly? what is the problem with **DataType**

**Code:**

```
model = load_model('model.h5')
print('2')
model.summary()
print('3')
m = model.get_weights()
print('4')
print(model.optimizer)
print('5')
print(model.layers)
print('6')
print(model.inputs)
print('7')
print(model.outputs)
print('8')
print(model.get_config())
print('9')
# ========================================================================================================
test_input = np.array(['hi'],['hoe'])
test_input = test_input.reshape((-1, 2))
test_output = model.predict(test_input, batch_size=1, verbose=0)
print(test_output)
```

**Error:**

> TypeError: data type not understood

Answer (score 0):

Try to give Typecode for string datatype you gave in test_input.

Answer (score 0):

can you reinstall the environment and try the same. Some times a bad environment setup can give you this error.

install (keras, tf) again and try